# Run task after android .apk installation

Tags: android

i m using GCM for push notification and i wanna known how to perform the registration task just after the app installation without any interaction of user.

can any one describe it... thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Your app, on Android 3.2+, is installed in the stopped state. Nothing of your code will run until something uses an explicit `Intent` to start one of your components. Normally, that will be the user tapping on your home screen launcher icon. You are welcome to do the GCM registration at that time.